# Read only field in UI component form Magento 2

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, ui-form

I have to add read only form field in UI component form. I have tried disabled input field but it is different from the readonly as described below.

According to magento documentation:

> Read-only Form Data:
>
> It may be necessary or advantageous to display form field data that cannot
> be changed or edited. In these cases the form label should appear to
> provide context for the “read-only” data, but not the field
> bounding-box so that it is clear to the user that the data cannot be
> edited.

Link: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/pattern-library/getting-user-input/form_elements/form_elements.html#read

[image: Read only field]

[image: Disabled field]

I have done a lot of research but can't figure it out by myself.
I will very grateful if someone can assist.

Comment: **For those who have marked this question as duplicate**, There is difference in the GUI of both read only and disabled fields as i have already described above. For convenience, i also added the **images**.